# Op-amp network topology to amplify positive (or negative) cycles only, keeping the complimentary cycles at unity gain

Tags: operational-amplifier

### Question

Does there exist an Op-Amp network topology to amplify only the positive, or negative cycles, whilst keeping the corresponding (negative, or positive) cycles at unity gain?

I want to send a small signal into an op-amp, amplify only the positive or negative cycles, then send the output into another op-amp to amplify the 'other cycle'.

### Prototype

[image: buffer, then amplify only positive cycles keeping negative at unity gain, then amplify only the negative cycles keeping positive cycles at unity gain, leading to the next stage/output]

### Avoid

I understating the the super diode/ precision half wave rectifier (Abbreviation: PHRF) allows for splitting of positive or negative cycles, but I am hesitant to split the incoming signal into two parallel routes, use two PHWRs to separate the positive and negative cycles and then use further stages to amplify the two routes, and then sum them with another op-amp for fear of incurring phase issues when recombining the signals.

[image: Split signal with two precision half wave rectifiers, amplify them separately and then sum the signals]

This plan is to feed a clipping stage for asymmetric clipping. As long as the clipped (guitar) signal does not suffer too much phase difference upon recombination as per 2nd image, the audio signal will be recognisable to the user.

It is important to be able to vary the positive and negative cycle amplification independently as this will give the asymmetric clipping.

Regards

Daniel

Comment: Ummm.  Why?  What's wrong with just amplifying it the same way everybody else does?  It looks like you want the same result, but are taking a roundabout and complicated way.

Comment: I intend to a symmetrically clip the output

Comment: Although you say you want to avoid a PHRF: You now that there are specialized IC like AD630 built exactly for this purpose? It is also used in Lock-In-Amplifier applications where phase-noise from recombination would be bad. What is your exact requirement  concerning the phase noise?

Comment: Then you need to look for a circuit that clips symmetrically.  The usual way would be two diodes in antiparallel across the feedback resistor of an opamp.  You follow that by a gain stage to bring the level back up to where you want it.

Comment: I do not have an exact specification, the application is an audio circuit which will be able to amplify positive and negative cycles independently. This will feed a clipping stage for asymmetric clipping. As long as the clipped (guitar) signal does not suffer too much phase tdiffetence upon recombination as per 2nd image, the audio signal will be recognisable to the user

Comment: Jre, it is important to be able to vary the asymmetric clipping

Comment: Symmetric or asymmetric?  One or the other....

Comment: I want to asymetrically clip the signal. I'm getting auto corrected left right and centre and the app is posting answers not comments - moved to laptop.

Comment: For asymmetric, use a resistor in series with each of the diodes in a symmetric clipper.  Varying those resistors will vary the gain in the direction for that diode.

Comment: Auto correct is the first thing I turn off on any phone or other program.  I make quite enough errors by myself without some stupid phone "correcting" what I meant into something else.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something here, the answer is a diode in the negative feedback loop.

Comment: JRE, This would work in 'soft clipping' where you put the anti-parallel diodes in the feedback loop. If i were to employ 'hard-clipping', where the anti-parallel diodes come after a resistor on the output of an op-amp, i'd still need a way of treating the positive and negative cycles independently

Comment: @DWD Are you trying to control the asymmetry of the clipping?  Continuously variable or discrete?

Comment: @Chris M, that's exactly the goal of this exercise.  I want to asymmetrically clip, with the ability to send the positive and negative cycles in at whatever amplitudes i so choose.  I could have gone down the antiparallel diode route, where one of the diodes is actually two or more  in series, but I want that's not fine tuned enough

Comment: Can you put numbers on your accuracy requirements without necessarily poo pooing one normally good idea. Also given that you wish to amplify a guitar, you aint really talking hifi so what is the problem?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm taking all comments seriously, and graciously.  I agree, we are not talking hi-fi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you want asymmetric clipping, I'm going to present you with a circuit that does that.

It DOES NOT solve your stated problem of separate gains for the positive and negative halves of the signal - I think that is just your imagined way to get what you wanted.

I'm going to use a symmetric clipper, but make the signal asymmetric.  The result is an asymmetrically clipped signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpxAlP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and OA1 are used to add a DC offset to the signal.  Add more than half of V+, and the positive half gets clipped more.  Add less than half of V+ and the negative half of the signal gets clipped more.  Adjust the level of the signal going in to adjust how much clipping is done, adjust R1 for the asymmetry.

Much simpler than trying to split the signal into halves, fiddle with them, then add them back together.

Comment: Thank you @JRE. Your comments and answer have given me much to think about and a way forward with the stated problem.

Comment: Basically a distorsion pedal for the guitar :D

Answer (score 2):

And another asymmetrical clipping circuit (but with more precision): -

[image]

U2 and U3 perform the clipping/clamping. U2 prevents the output signal rising above V3 (can be set with a pot) and U3 prevents the output signal falling below V4 (can also be set with a pot). You can check what the output looks like courtesy of [this website](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/limiting-op-amp-output/).

Answer (score 1):

Your reticence to split the signal, process the two halves independently, and resassemble them pretty much rules out analog techniques.  The alternative is to sample, process using DSP, and then output the new signal with a DAC.

I'd say try it with precision half wave rectifiers.  More than likely, its good enough.  I don't anticipate phase issues at audio frequencies.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Seidman, I need to go down the analogue route, and am pleased to hear you think the PHWR will suffice for the application.